# Restricting Android camera

Tags: android, camera, android-intent

Avoiding having to create a whole camera app myself, I am calling up:

```
Intent camera = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
this.startActivityForResult(camera, PICTURE_RESULT);
```

However, the camera is very advanced and beautiful :) but not for my purposes.  :(
Is there a way to restrict the camera to control size, resolution, disable setup button, flash, face recognition, etc...?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry but you will be unable to change all these features using the **Intents** system. For this level of control you will have to create you own camera program.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html

You can change the autofocus and flash however using the uses tag in the **manifest.xml**